# Route [login] not defined On Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, url-routing, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I'm using routes/web.php

```
Route::get('login', [
 'as' => 'login-get',
 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
]);
```

and i'm calling it from the front-end like this:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('login-get') }}">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
```

and it throws me

**Route [login-get] not defined** :  *Error*

but when i change to :

```
Route::get('auth/login', [
 'as' => 'login-get',
 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
]);
```

**It goes Fine**

but it trows me a **404 error**

because of the href: *[IP]/auth/login*

so if anybody have the answer help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it using

**url** instead of **route**

and login the url directly.

like this:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('login') }}">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
```

:
but still i dont understand somebody knows !!!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to name it.

> Route::get('auth/login', [
>   'as' => 'login-get',
>   'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
>   ])**->name("login");**